# How to Create Blog existing wordpress Website?

Tags: wordpress

I have existing wordpress site  and add a blog in existing  wordpress site , 
i have  want to another link add this sub domain of existing wordpress site for create a new blog.but i don't know how to create blog ,
how to add blog in existing wordpress site and
how to  blog link configure in  sub domain in existing wordpress site .

plz help me  to easy step by step  create a  blog .

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Use `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` in wp-config.php.